Unterschied zwischen "Du hast keine vier Arme" und "Du hast nicht vier Arme"
Ich habe eine Frage zur Verwendung von "keine" und "nicht" in den folgenden Sätzen:

Du hast keine vier Arme(;du hast nur zwei)


Du hast nicht vier Arme(;du hast nur zwei)

Ich denke, dass beide Sätze grammatikalisch korrekt sind, aber ich möchte verstehen, ist "keine" hier besser geeignet als "nicht"? Wie verstehen Muttersprachler die oben genannten Sätze?

Grundsätzlich bedeuten beide Sätze das selbe und der Unterschied liegt bestenfalls in Nuancen.

Du hast nicht vier Arme

ist lediglich die Verneinung eines bestimmten Umstands. Wieviel Arme der Angesprochene nun tatsächlich hat, bleibt offen - nur, daß es eben nicht vier sind.
Hingegen ist

Du hast keine vier Arme

so - wohlgemerkt, tendenziell - so zu verstehen, daß der Angesprochene weniger als vier hat. "Keine + irgendeine Mengenangabe" bedeutet üblicherweise, daß die Mengenangabe unterschritten wird und nicht, daß sie einfach irgendwie unzutreffend ist. Zum Beispiel:

Bis Weihnachten sind es keine 5 Tage (mehr).

bedeutet normalerweise, daß es weniger als 5 Tage sind, auch wenn das "mehr" am Schluß (das die Aussage ausdrücklich eindeutig macht) weggelassen wird.
Kleine Nachbemerkung:
Daß "keine + Mengenangabe" üblicherweise "weniger als" bedeutet, macht sich etwa die Formulierung

Bis Weihnachten sind es keine 4 Tage, sondern 5.

zunutze: zunächst wird mit der bekannten Formulierung eine Erwartung (weniger als 4) aufgebaut, die dann aber mit der Richtigstellung gewendet und die ursprünglich angenommene Bedeutung in ihr Gegenteil verkehrt wird.
Humor wird, nach Sigmud Freud (Der Witz und seine Beziehung zum Unterbewußten), durch den Wechsel des Kontexts erzeugt. Dieser Wechsel geschieht hier in Form der Verkehrung des Subtexts.

Ich denke, wenn mein Oktopus mit 7 Schrimps jonglieren will, sollte ich nicht sagen "Das wird nix, Du hast keine 4 Arme!" wenn er 8 hat, sondern nur, wenn er 3 oder weniger hat, da hier überzählige Arme nicht ins Gewicht fallen. Genau 4 Arme zu haben ist eine Teilmenge von mindestens 4 Arme zu haben. Es hängt aber sehr vom Kontext ab, und der Betonung. "hast nicht 4 Arme (sondern 8)" vs. "hast nicht 4 Arme" (schwach nur betont).

Ja, in diesem Zusammenhang ist der Bedeutungsunterschied in der Betonung auf die Unterschreitung eines Mindestmasses bei "keine". Daneben ist aber auch ein leichter Unterschied daß bei "du hast nicht..." das "nicht" sich
sowohl als Negation von "haben" als auch also Negation von "vier" deuten läßt. Wenn ich z.B. sage: "Du machst mir keine Angst" wird "Angst" als substantivisches angesehen das man quantitative messen kann, und bei "Du machst mir nicht Angst" ist das nicht wiederum klar auf das Verb bezogen.
